# Как исправить проблему с отображением картинки в html

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

Столкнулся с такой проблемой что при использовании тега  в html не отображается картинка хотя путь к изображению указан правильно. Расширение изображение jpg.

```
<div class="images"> 
    <div class="image"> 
        <img src="contents_image/first_image.jpg" alt="test text"> 
    </div> 
   </div>
```

Буду рад если сможете помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще нужно больше информации чтобы понять Вашу проблему... Обычно в заголовках HTML нужно указать путь к файлу со стилями например:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename= 'page.css')}}"/>
```

А потом уже в теле страницы

```
<img src="{{item}}" width="250" height="200" >
```

где значение `item` задается в обработчике страницы:

```
return render_template('page.html',item = url_for('static', filename= 'nameImage.jpeg'))
```

Соответственно изображение должно находиться в директории 'static'